# SMTP servers for bulk mailing

Tags: email, smtp

I got the authority from the user, and they subscribe to my newsletter.

Are there any free bulk mailing SMTP servers?

If not, which service (e.g., MailChimp) offers the largest mail-sent limit and subscriber limit?

In fact, can I build my own SMTP server and serve email just like MailChimp, given that my computer can handle the workload?

Answer (score 0):

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) offers up to 2000 contacts for free as long as you aren't spamming, so there's your best option.

You can definitely build your own SMTP server and roll your own mailing list software (MailChimp won't let you use your own, AFAIK) but you'd have to ensure that you are whitelisted in as many places as possible, have proper SPF records and DKIM in place, and your IP has a good reputation.